# SIGINT handelling in Duktape

Tags: c, sigint, duktape

anyone know how I can handle SIGINT (interrupt signals) when working with [Duktape](http://duktape.org/api.html)? I would like to throw an exception that I can catch in the javascript when the user interrupts using CTRL+C.

I have a function to catch the signal, but my current method of just calling

```
duk_throw(duk_context);
```

as my signal handler is not very reliable. I'm guessing the engine is in a bad state at that point so can't carry on.

Anyone have any ideas?

I thought about setting a flag somewhere, but no sure how to do this cleanly.

Thank you

Matt